# How to assign Keys to Variables in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to assign Keys to Variables in pyqt5?

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    var = "Qt.Key_F"
    if event.key() == var:
        print("you press key F")
```

**Edit-:**  For more and clear pictures, add the following script. In my code,  The first and second event produce the result as desired and prints the result But the third event, which is assigned/got it from dictionery(**Alt+Z**), is  not produce/prints any results . How to resolve it ?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

dict_scut = {
    "eng":{ "A": "Qt.Key_A", "B": "Qt.Key_B","C": "Qt.Key_C","D": "Qt.Key_D","E": "Qt.Key_E","F": "Qt.Key_F",
            "G": "Qt.Key_G", "H": "Qt.Key_H","I": "Qt.Key_I","J": "Qt.Key_J","K": "Qt.Key_K","L": "Qt.Key_L",
            "M": "Qt.Key_M", "N": "Qt.Key_N","O": "Qt.Key_O","P": "Qt.Key_P","Q": "Qt.Key_Q","R": "Qt.Key_R",
            "S": "Qt.Key_S", "T": "Qt.Key_T","U": "Qt.Key_U","V": "Qt.Key_V","W": "Qt.Key_W","X": "Qt.Key_X",
            "Y": "Qt.Key_Y", "Z": "Qt.Key_Z","None":""}
             }

dict_modi = {"None":" ","alt":"Qt.AltModifier","ctrl":"Qt.ControlModifier","shift":"Qt.ShiftModifier",
             "altctrl":"Qt.AltModifier|Qt.ControlModifier","altshift":"Qt.AltModifier|Qt.ShiftModifier",
             "ctrlshift":"Qt.ControlModifier|Qt.ShiftModifier",
             "altctrlshift":"Qt.AltModifier|Qt.ControlModifier|Qt.ShiftModifier"}

class Dynamic_shortcut(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Dynamic Widget")

        self.var_modi_1 = Qt.AltModifier
        self.var_scut_1 = Qt.Key_A

        user1_modi = "alt"
        user1_scut = "Z"
        self.var_modi_2 = dict_modi.get(user1_modi)
        self.var_scut_2 = dict_scut['eng'].get(user1_scut)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.AltModifier and event.key() == Qt.Key_Q:
            print("Pressed key : Alt + Q")
        if event.modifiers() == self.var_modi_1 and event.key() == self.var_scut_1:
            print("Pressed key : Alt + A")
        if event.modifiers() == self.var_modi_2 and event.key() == self.var_scut_2:
            print("pressed key : Alt + Z")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dynamic_shortcut()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Let's back up a step. Why do you want to do this? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @code Apprentice, assign shorcut dynamically

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , Need to assign shortcuts programmatically. if the user needs to change a shortcut from the default key to the desired key. Thanks to give the solution

Comment: @Code-Apprentice,, add the full detailed script in my edits

Comment: I suggest you learn about the difference between strings and variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your goal is to detect which letter is pressed and perform some action if it matches the value of a variable, if so the solution is to use event.text():

```py
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    v = "F"
    if event.text() == var:
        # OR
        # if event.text().upper() == var:
        print("you press key F")
```

You are complicating your work, Qt already has classes that allow you to handle this logic in a simple way through [`QKeySequence`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html) and [`QShortcut`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QShortcut, QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        keysequence1 = QKeySequence("ALT+A")
        # OR
        # keysequence1 = QKeySequence(Qt.ALT + Qt.Key_A)
        shorcut1 = QShortcut(keysequence1, self, activated=self.handle_activated)

        keysequence2 = QKeySequence("alt+z")
        # OR
        # keysequence1 = QKeySequence(Qt.ALT + Qt.Key_Z)
        shorcut2 = QShortcut(keysequence2, self, activated=self.handle_activated)

    def handle_activated(self):
        self.do_task()

    def do_task(self):
        print("Qt is Awesome!!!")


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to have a more user friendly environment for setting a QKeySequence then you can use [`QKeySequenceEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html).

Comment: I need to assign a shortcut programmatically. For Example, if user1 use "Alt + A" as a shortcut for button1  but user2 is not comfortable with shortcut "Alt +A" and he needs to change "Alt + S" as a shortcut for the same button

Comment: For a More clear picture, add the  detailed script in my edits

Comment: @tckraomuqnt see my update

Answer (score 1):

```
var = "Qt.Key_F"
```

This assigns a string to the variable. That string has nothing to do with Qt or "keys". I think what you want instead is

```
var = Qt.Key_F
```

But this is not really necessary since `Key_F` is already a variable. You can use it directly:

```
if event.key() == Qt.Key_F:
```